How to host .onion website on the same server with normal sites (nginx)?
I have a running NginX server which already serves some .com sites. All work fine, as far as I'm concerned. I've also installed TOR and it is running, the .onion address is generated fine in the /var/lib/tor/hidden/hostname file. But when I try to access the address in the TOR Browser, the URL does not load.
According to tutorials I've read, I've done this:

in /etc/tor/torcc I have:

HiddenServiceDir /var/lib/tor/hidden/
HiddenServicePort 80 unix:/var/run/tor-hidden-service.sock
#HiddenServicePort 80 127.0.0.1:80 #tried
#HiddenServicePort 443 127.0.0.1:443 #tried



in /etc/nginx/sites-available/torsite:

server {
listen unix:/var/run/tor-hidden-service.sock;
#listen 127.0.0.1:80; #tried
#listen 80; #tried 
#listen [::]:80; #tried

server_name mylongoniondaddress.onion;
error_log /var/www/tor.log;
root /var/www/tor; #here there's an accessible index.html file
index index.html index.php;
}

According to what I've learned, this should work, as well as all the other combinations I've marker with #tried; obviously those didn't work, with mostly making impossible to re/start nginx or tor. The tor.log is empty.
I don't know where else to look and what to try next. Any ideas?
Thank you.
PS forgot to mention I'm running Ubuntu 22.04

Alright then...keep your secrets.

verify correct permissions and owner on sock file make sure both tor and nginx can read / write, also make sure it exists. Also check nginx error logs since tor logs contain nothing.
